# Connecting to codefresh image registry via kubectl, problem with secrets

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl, codefresh

I am trying to deploy an application via kubectl using an image stored on Codefresh. I have it running perfectly when i place the image on a public registry.

The problem is when I apply the deployment.yaml I get a "ImagePullBackOff" error on the pods. I'm assuming, i think correctly, that this is because I need a secret to be able to access my Codefresh image.

This is the container part of my current deployment.yaml:

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: dockapp
        #States the image that will be put inside the pod. Secret to get access is declared below
        #registry.hub.docker.com/jamiedovu/dockapp:latest
          image:  r.cfcr.io/jamiew87/my-app-image:master
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: http
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

My question is, what is it i need to put into the secret "regcred" to be able to connect to this private registry. The Kubernetes documentation only demonstrates how to do one for docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [it's explained in the docs](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/deploy-to-kubernetes/access-docker-registry-from-kubernetes/#creating-the-docker-registry-secret).

```
export DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER=r.cfcr.io
export DOCKER_USER=YOUR_USERNAME
export DOCKER_PASSWORD=YOUR_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
export DOCKER_EMAIL=YOUR_EMAIL

kubectl create secret docker-registry cfcr\
 --docker-server=$DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER\
 --docker-username=$DOCKER_USER\
 --docker-password=$DOCKER_PASSWORD\
 --docker-email=$DOCKER_EMAIL
```

Comment: OK this part-helps. I Dont directly log in to codefresh, i Oauth in using google, which means I dont have a codefresh password, so what would i put into this space?

Answer (score 0):

For people in the future with problems,
The codefresh repository is an actual docker repository. Not knowing this was giving me the problems.
So in the docker-username etc places you put your codefresh credentials, and instead of the password you put a secret that you generate within codefresh. This gives you access to the r.cfcr.io repository.